# Canadian Mathematical Olympiad 1987, Problem 4

Tags: contest-math, solution-verification

On a large flat field, $n$ people $(n>1)$ are positioned so that for each person the distances to all the other people are different. Each person holds a water pistol and at a given signal fires and hits the person who is closest. When $n$ is odd, show that there is at least one person left dry.

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2461911/how-would-i-go-about-solving-this-tricky-induction-problem) is a variant of the question I am asking but I am not using induction in my approach.

***My Approach:***

Our primary goal is to ensure that no person remains dry.

When a total of $k$ people are present ($k$ is odd), it is evident that if no one remains dry, then a closed chain must have been formed when considering the order of firing. (Since the pairing doesn't change the parity, atleast one dry person will remain in the end)

WLOG, let $P_1$ attack $P_2$, $P_2$ attack $P_3$, $P_3$ attack $P_4$ and so on till $P_{k-1}$ attack $P_k$ and $P_k$ attack $P_1$

Let us denote the distance between $P_i$ and $P_j$ as $i_j$ or $j_i$

Now $2_3<2_1$ since $P_2$ attacks $P_3$, thus $2_3<1_2$. Similarly $3_4<3_2$ since $P_3$ attack $P_4$, thus $3_4<2_3<1_2$

$\therefore $ In the end, we get $k_1<(k-1)_k<(k-2)_{k-1}<\ldots<3_4<2_3<1_2$

From this we can see $k_1=1_k<1_2$ which implies that $P_1$ must have attacked $P_k$ instead of $P_2$ which is a contradiction.

This means that $P_1$ and $P_k$ attacks each other while $P_2$ attacks $P_3$, $P_3$ attacks $P_4$ and so on till $P_{k-1}$ attacks $P_k$ hence leaving an open chain where $P_2$ remains dry.

It can be observed that any pairing will result in an open chain consisting the pair if any of the remaining person attacks a person from the pair. If none of the remaining persons attack any person from pair, then the pair can be isolated and similar argument can be used for remaining $(k-2)$ people.

$\therefore $ We will always get an open chain if the number of persons are odd which means that atleast one person will remain dry.

Please check my solution for any mistakes. Also please suggest any improvements in the solution.

***THANKS***

Comment: Consider the minimal distance between any two people... those two people must fire at each other, so there is always a pair which shoots at each other.

Comment: @lulu Even after excluding all such pairs, we would still remain with an odd number which means that closed chains cannot be formed

Comment: The first line of your argument is "assuming that no one fires at each other".  That assumption is impossible, so whatever follows from it is not useful.

Comment: If nobody else fires at either member of the minimal pair then you can remove the pair (and you are done by induction).  If somebody else fires at one member of the minimal pair then a simple counting argument works.

Comment: @lulu, If we remove that assumption, I don't think it affects the argument that "a closed chain cannot be formed with odd number of elements", There I proved that $k_1$ is the minimum distance which means that $1$ and $k$ must have attacked each other in contradiction to $1$ attacking $2$. This infact, helps my argument that a closed chain cannot be formed. Is that correct?

Comment: But why must the chain have an odd number of elements?

Comment: @lulu If any closed chain can be formed containing odd number of elements, then that means that each element of chain is connected to two other elements or we can say that no one remains dry. I needed to contradict this statement. If no one remains dry, then the only ways are either pairing or closed chains. On pairing in odd numbers, 1 element will remain at the end in the most extreme case. Thus I only needed to prove that closed chains cannot exist.

Comment: I think you are trying to patch up a bad argument.  I think you'll find it a lot easier to proceed along the lines I suggested in an earlier comment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111304/discussion-between-devansh-kamra-and-lulu).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the comments:

The argument as written is not correct.  The initial assumption, that no pair fires on each other, is not possible.  The two people $A,B$ at minimal distance from each other must fire at each other. (of course the case where there is only one person is trivial).

Two ways to solve the problem:

Method I: consider that minimal pair $A,B$.  We distinguish two cases (according to whether anyone else shoots at either $A$ or $B$).

Since the case $n=1$ is trivial it makes sense to proceed by induction.  Let's assume we have a counterexample with minimal $n$ (we will derive a contradiction).

If nobody else shoots at $A,B$ then we can ignore that pair and focus on the $n-2$ remaining people.  By the induction hypothesis, at least one of those stays dry and we are done.

If somebody else, $C$ say, shoots at one of them, say $A$, then at least two people shoot at $A$.  It follows that the map $F: \{1,\cdots, n\}\to \{1,\cdots,n\}$ which maps the $i^{th}$ person to their target is not injective.  Thus it can't be surjective and again we are done.

Method II (sketch).  Suppose we had a collection with odd $n$ in which nobody stayed dry. Then consider the shooting pattern.  Since it must be the case that everyone shoots at (and is shot at by) a unique person, the collection must break up into distinct closed loops.  These can't all have  length $2$ since the collection is odd.  There must, in fact, be an odd loop of length $>2$. But consider the members of that loop.  There must be a minimal distance between any two members of that loop and, as before, we quickly see that those two people can't shoot at anyone else in that loop.  Thus the loop is not possible, and we are done.

Comment: I agree, but I just wanted to know that is this argument acceptable ignoring the length and difficulty of this argument. If not, then please help me find some other flaw in this. (The assumption that no one fires at each other, even if removed does not affect the closed chain argument. It is also proven when $k_1$ is minimal, that there is atleast one pair $1$ and $k$ firing at each other. )

Comment: As it stands your argument is wrong for the reasons I have given.  If you believe you can rewrite the argument so that it does not depend on a false assumption, please do that.  Don't just leave the vital repairs in a string of comments, edit the post to include the complete, revised proof.

Comment: Note:  I added a sketch of an alternative proof which I think is closer to what you were trying to do.

Comment: This more or less resembles what I was trying to do. As a matter of fact, it simplifies it to a great extent. Thank you for your help!!!